# Coding of data font non editable in shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, font

What is the reason for a shape layer to have the field "Codificación de la fuente de datos" (coding of data font) selectable or not?

In the following image the red arrow shows the dropdown list in grey and changing it is not possible.

[image]

Sorry, my version of QGIS 2.18.11 is in Spanish.

I usually go to properties of the layer > General > Layer information, and there I can change the data font codification.

For more info: the shapefile is a real shapefile, it is possible to edit it, and it is saved in the same folder as other shapefiles that I can actually change this property from the drop-down list. Also my coworkers open it and can change the coding of the data font.

Comment: Is the layer both really a shape-file and saved somewhere? Non-shape-file are usually not (fully) editable, same goes for temporary data sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, it is a shape-file and it is saved in the same folder as other shape-files that I can change this property. I edited my question to specify this aspects, for more information

Comment: May be someone else is using it and locking it, or the lock file was not removed from the folder, just check if along the normal different shp file there is a lock file and try to erase it

Comment: No one else is using it and I didn't find any lock file around. I saved the shape-file again and still didn't allowed me to change the font coding; however, when I saved it again choosing "System" from the coding options of the save as... menu, then the new shape-file does have the drop-down list available.